# how to make today date (v-present) always the middle column in vuetify calendar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vcalendar

vuetify v-calendar has specific days order (sun to sat) in Type week, then moving class v-present from left to right according today date, how to make today date that has (v-present) in the middle column [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ7Nk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much time of searching and reading docs more over and over i found a work around solution,v-calendar takes a prop called weekdays its an array in which week starts at sun (0) and ends at sat (6) this is the default form `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` for that prop so i created weekDays  in data property then running this method in mounted hook it works

```
 getWeekDays() {
    const dayNames = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    let dateObj = new Date();
    let dayName = dayNames[dateObj.getDay()];

    switch(dayName){
      case"Sun":
        this.weekDays = [4,5,6,0,1,2,3]
        break;
      case"Mon":
        this.weekDays = [5,6,0,1,2,3,4]
        break;
      case"Tues":
        this.weekDays = [6,0,1,2,3,4,5]
        break;
      case"Wed":
        this.weekDays = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
        break;
      case"Thu":
        this.weekDays = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]
        break;
      case"Fri":
        this.weekDays = [2,3,4,5,6,0,1]
        break;
      case"Sat":
        this.weekDays = [3,4,5,6,0,1,2]
        break;
        default:
        this.weekDays = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
},
```